# Best practice for naming akka-actors (in the companion object)

Tags: scala, akka, akka-actor

I have several akka-actors defined like this:

```scala
object SomethingActor {
  val name: String = "somethingActor"
  def props: Props = Props(new SomethingActor())
}

class somethingActor extends Actor {
  verride def receive: Receive = ???
}

// somewhere else
final val myActor = actorSystem.actorOf(SomethingActor.props, SomethingActor.name)
```

Of these actors, only up to one single instant is "alive" at any given moment of my application, so e.g. a new `SomethingActor` actor can only be created if the old `SomethingActor` is dead.

Now, I don't think defining the actor name like this: `val name: String = "somethingActor"` is very nice, so I have been wondering if I can use something like this:

```scala
object SomethingActor {
  val name: String = this.getClass.getName
  def props: Props = Props(new SomethingActor())
}
```

Would this be considered bad practice? Is there a better way to handle this? I (think I) need to save the name in the companion object to be able to search for the actor from another point in my program using `ActorSystem.actorSelection(path: String)` ([docu](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/actor/ActorSystem.html)).

Comment: I think `this.getClass.getName` is a good practice. `Of these actors, only up to one single instant is alive at any given moment of my application` Kindly confirm the mentioned feature you want or not ?

Comment: `Of these actors, only up to one single instant is alive at any given moment of my application` This is the case in my application and I do not intend to change that. :)

Comment: Then I think your approach is a good.